# Secondary hard drive loop?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, clicking-sound

I just did a complete cleaning of my Windows 7 PC, blowing out all the dust and such. When I put it all together again, a cable was pinched in between the chassis and a fan. It started out making a grinding noise, so instead of waiting for it to finish a boot up, I pushed the button for 5 seconds and shut it down.

When I got it all back together again, I booted it up, and it took way longer to boot. I kept hearing the drive (secondary for storage) winding up, clicking, and winding down. I let it boot up to full screen, then shut it down, checked my cables, and rebooted. It came back up doing the same thing. I then went into Computer Management, and it showed up as being installed, so I exited Computer management, and attempted to navigate to the drive through Windows Explorer. It opened up for a few seconds, then the window closed, and it disappeared from the My Computer view in Windows Explorer.

I rebooted, and when it came up again, it started putting up repeat windows of "Need to Format Hard drive before use". Despite this, when I navigated to the drive through Windows Explorer the first time, all the original folders were there. Did the shutdown during start up, after physically cleaning the computer, mess something up on the secondary hard drive? This is the first time this has happened.

Comment: Sounds like the drive is dead.  The fact you heard grinding noise is not a good sign.  The fact it was having problems spinning up is a really bad sign.  You have had hard mechanical failure.  In other words there isn't anything that can be done.  Hopeful you have backups because you will need them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you secondary drive is dead now, because you hear noise. Might be your hard disk having physical issue. I would suggest you to simply interchange the data cable(sata/ide) with different port and swap the power cable.

There is a very less chance to work but if i would be on your place then i will try it.